# Create a real terminate session in NodeJS

Tags: node.js, child-process

I have a Discord bot, which has a command called `execute`. This command will execute the command that I provided. The problem is, I can't save the progress of the terminal.

For example: I used the command to change directory to `/discord-bot/test` (`cd ./test`). When I use the command again, it didn't save the progress of the last terminal session. The directory of the new session was `/discord-bot/` (original)

Expecting:

Me: `!execute`

Bot: You have 3 minutes to execute the command

Me: `cd ./test && pwd`

Bot: `/discord-bot/test`

Me: `pwd`

Bot: `/discord-bot/test`

Result:

Me: `!execute`

Bot: You have 3 minutes to execute the command

Me: `cd ./test && pwd`

Bot: `/discord-bot/test`

Me: `pwd`

Bot: `/discord-bot/`

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.